# Div id not recognised for justGage in angular 2

Tags: angular, justgage

I am creating a component for gauges using JustGage in angular 2.

Following is my component,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-gauge',
    template: '<div id={{gaugeId}} style="width:200px; height:150px;" ></div>'
})
export class GaugeComponet implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    gaugeId: String;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("inside on init with id : " + this.gaugeId);
        var g = new JustGage({
            id: this.gaugeId,
            value: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: "Title"
        });
    }
}
```

and its usage in app component,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Gauge Demo</h1> <my-gauge gaugeId="testId"></my-gauge>',
    directives :[GaugeComponet]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

When I am running this code I am getting the following output in my browser console ,

```
inside on init with id : testId GaugeComponent.js (line 16)
* justgage: No element with id : testId found
```

When I hardcode the id in gauge component , I am able to see the gauge on my page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass `testId` as string.

Try this:

```
<my-gauge gaugeId="'testId'"></my-gauge>
```

Or you need to have the `testId` variable in your `AppComponent`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Gauge Demo</h1> <my-gauge gaugeId="testId"></my-gauge>',
    directives :[GaugeComponet]
})
export class AppComponent {
  testId = 'testId';
}
```

**Update**

You also need to use `ngAfterViewInit` hook instead of `ngOnInit` to init JustGage

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3002-correlating-directive-life-cycle-events-to-dom-state-in-angularjs-2-beta-1.htm

Comment: I tried passing the id in variable as [gaugeId]="variableName" but still it wasn't working and for the first apporoach i got this 'inside on init with id : 'testId'
GaugeComponent.js (line 16)
* justgage: No element with id : 'testId' found'. Also i am getting id in my component if u see the console's output I am getting the Id.

Comment: Also can u suggest me some links where I can learn the lifecycle methods better ??